# Is there a way to sort projects in Eclipse GGTS?

Tags: eclipse, grails

I am using the Groovy-Grails Tool Suite (GGTS) which is basically just Eclipse with some Groovy/Grails specific stuff on top of it.

I added a new source folder (Properties > Java Build Path) but it is appearing in a weird order. Is there any way I can manually order the source folders in Project Explorer?

You can see in this image that the "test/functional" source folder is not next to the other test folders. At a minimum I'd like to have them all together, and ideally I'd like to choose the order. There are some other folders I'd like to move around too if I could.

I also want to keep using this Project Explorer view since it puts a Grails specific spin on things, like the "domain," "controllers," "views," and others.

[image: Project Explorer]

I am using GGTS 3.1.0.RELEASE which looks like it is built on Eclipse 4.2.1.

Comment: It looks like the order is defined in the org.grails.ide.eclipse.explorer plugin. Here's the code: https://github.com/SpringSource/grails-ide/blob/master/org.grails.ide.eclipse.explorer/src/org/grails/ide/eclipse/explorer/preferences/OrderingConfig.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how I missed it, but under Preferences > Grails > Project Explorer you can order the default set of objects (domain, controllers, etc).  That would help with part of my problem of wanting to order all the objects.

After I did that, I exported the preferences (File > Export > Preferences > All) to a file. In that file I found a String like this:

```
/instance/org.grails.ide.eclipse.explorer/org.grails.ide.eclipse.explorer.ordering
```

I updated that, adding "`Stest/functional;`" after "`Stest/integration;`", imported the preferences (File > Import > Preferences), and restarted the workspace.

I wish the plugin's preferences (where you can change the default ordering) allowed you to add new objects right in the preference editor, but at least there is some way to do it.